# Javascript code to verify a URL works in IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to determine whether a file exists on a site. I'm checking for large files, so I don't need to wait for it to download, I just need to know if it exists. When I run the code on IE (11.0.9600.17843) or Chrome (43.0.2357.134), it returns true for the file. When I run it on Firefox (39.0), it returns null for the same file.

```
    function checkUrl(url) {
        var aborted = false;
        try {

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var timer = Date.now();
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if ((request.readyState > 1) & (request.status === 200)) {
                    aborted = true;
                    request.abort();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            request.open('GET', url, false);
            request.send();
            if (request.status === 200) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
            if (aborted) { return true; }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why it's not working on Firefox?

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working in Firefox, but you could just issue a HEAD request instead of a GET and not worry about aborting the request.

Comment: You can't do that. http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: @Trevon, that works. If you add that as a answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of issuing a GET request you can just issue a HEAD request. HEAD requests will only return the headers of the requested resource, not the body, so it's perfect for querying the existence of files.